# Why am I unable to access my node server running on port 3001 from my React app running on port 3000?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to access my API running on port `3001` from my react app running on port 3000 but I am getting the following error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /%3Canonymous%3E from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
```

I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

Comment: This question does not make a whole lot of sense. React is a client side javascript library not a server application.

Comment: What part doesn't make sense to you? I am trying to access Node from React, where does it say that React is not a client side library?

Comment: "from react running on port 3000"  You have established you have an api  on 3001 and that you have an unknown application running on 3000.  It sounds like you might be trying to make an ajax call call to one of them?

Comment: This sounds very much like an X/Y problem. Can you go into how you got to this point? how is the request being made, from where to where, etc

Comment: Is your server actually running? You need to open another terminal/command line and write `node filename.js` and make sure nothing breaks. Then try to make the request/refresh your react app. If you're still having problems please check and add whatever is logged in both terminals/command lines.

Comment: @MattCroak Yes, my node server is running. I have posted the error from the React terminal in my original question. There is nothing shown in the node terminal because the call is not hitting the server.

Comment: Are you running on a mac? If so, using `127.0.0.3001` as the port might work.

Comment: Running on Window.

Comment: Have you tried adding a slash after `http://localhost:3001`? So change your `proxy` script to `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"`

Answer (score 0):

start both frontend and backend concurrently
like:
 previous- "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" && \"npm run server\""

and Changed it to "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\""

or else 
change proxy to "http://localhost:3001" instead of "https://localhost:3000"